# Emacs and Clojure method call hierarchy

Tags: emacs, clojure

I use eclipse to develop in Java, because it has a lots of useful features. Some frequently used are "Open Declaration" and "Open Call hierarchy".

**Open Declaration** - If i use somewhere some function i just press F3 (hotkey) and get the file with cursor pointed to its definition.

**Call Hierarchy** - shows the tree of calls this method.

For programming on clojure i use emacs as IDE.

I'm interested if Emacs support such functionality or exists some plugins to add this?

Note: I can perform regex search on method name to find definition but it not always gives unique results.

Comment: As a substitute for Open Declaration, you can enter (source function-name) in the repl. e.g. (source println) and it will print the source for you. It only works on functions that have been loaded from a file though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In emacs with SLIME/swank-clojure, you can go to the definition of a var (including function declarations) by pressing M-. which calls slime-edit-definition

There's also a slime-who-calls function under C-c C-w C-c which may be some kind of substitute for call hierarchy

Comment: Outstanding! M-. - exactly what i need, but call hierarchy working a bit strange.